# Getting 403 forbidden error while accessing linkedIn 2.0 API from SharePoint 2013 web part

Tags: linkedin-api

API: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)

App Permission: r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, w_share

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        string requesturl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)";


        HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(requesturl) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Host = "api.linkedin.com";
        //webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //webRequest.Connection = "Keep-Alive";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        //Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

        //String postData = String.Empty;
        //byte[] postArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        //dataStream.Write(postArray, 0, postArray.Length);
        //dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();


        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        String returnVal = responseReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using V2 API and you did not taken permission to use r_basicprofile then either apply for permission to use r_basicprofile to linkedin

OR use r_liteprofile + r_emailaddress for V2
(also check r_liteprofile  permission is there in your app or not )

r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id 
r_emailaddress for getting emailAddress

Check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context